# How to disable gravity only for a specific model in Gazebo?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

A similar question has been answered. http://answers.ros.org/question/65991/how-to-disable-gravity-of-a-model-in-the-world-only-disable-one-model/

However, this only works for the .sdf model files. It does not work for urdf. Kindly help.

```
<link name="base_link" gravity="0 0 0">
    <gravity>0</gravity>
  </link>

  <joint name="base_joint" type="fixed">
    <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
    <parent link="base_link" />
    <child link="body_link" />
  </joint>

  <link name="body_link">
    <gravity>0</gravity>
    <inertial>
      <mass value="0.1" />
      <origin xyz="0 0 0" />
      <inertia ixx="1" ixy="0" ixz="0" iyy="1" iyz="0" izz="1" />
    </inertial>

    <visual name="base_visual">
      <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry name="pioneer_geom">
        <mesh filename="package://rotors_description/meshes/simple_airplane1.dae" />
      </geometry>
    </visual>

    <collision>
      <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://rotors_description/meshes/simple_airplane1.dae" />
      </geometry>
    </collision>
    
  </link>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/13416/how-to-disable-gravity-only-for-a-specific-model-in-gazebo?/) by [webvenky](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1202/webvenky/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 23 on 2016-05-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

It looks like your file is in the URDF format (you use `origin` instead of `pose` for example).

`<gravity>` within a link is specified in SDF, but not in URDF. Luckily, the conversion from URDF to SDF is possible. In order to use SDF tags within your URDF link, use the `<gazebo>` tag, as explained in [this](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials/?tut=ros_urdf#%3Cgazebo%3EElementsForLinks) tutorial. It should look something like this:

```
  <gazebo reference="base_link">
    <gravity>0</gravity>
  </gazebo>
```

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2016-05-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [webvenky](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1202/webvenky/) on 2016-05-26**:
Thanks a lot! It works. :-)

**Comment by [hbaqueiro](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5170/hbaqueiro/) on 2018-11-05**:
Does it remain static in the world even if something collide with it? I was looking for something more like the  tag.

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2018-11-05**:
No, it will not remain static, it will just not be affected by gravity. There's no way to set only one link to be static, that tag works only on the model level. You can however make a model static and connect it to a non-static model with a joint.

**Comment by [BrumBrum](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/22144/brumbrum/) on 2020-01-07**:
For me the  tags did not work, this did work however:

```
<gazebo reference="base_link">
   <turnGravityOff>true</turnGravityOff>
</gazebo>
```

**Comment by [myboyhood](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/26240/myboyhood/) on 2020-05-04**:
For me  or  can not stop model to drop down to the ground,
in order to ensure model in the air, I fixed it in the world link

```
  <link name="world"/>
```

```
<parent link="world"/>

<child link="link1"/>

  </joint>
```

**Comment by [val](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/28837/val/) on 2020-08-07**:
I tried both  and   but none of them turned gravity off. When I check the generated sdf file it shows that there are two tags defining gravity. Adding the tag in Urdf file doesn't overwrite the default value. it just adds another tag.

```
<gravity>0</gravity>
<gravity>1</gravity>
```

Does anyone know how i can overwrite the original tag?

**Comment by [th123](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/41084/th123/) on 2021-01-21**:
Hi val,
have you found a solution for this problem by now? I assume I am facing the same issue.

**Comment by [danzimmerman](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/41990/danzimmerman/) on 2021-02-17**:
Yep I'm hitting this now too (ROS Melodic + Gazebo9)

Related to https://github.com/osrf/sdformat/issues/71 ?

**Comment by [danzimmerman](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/41990/danzimmerman/) on 2021-02-17**:
@th123 `<turnGravityOff>1</turnGravityOff>` (case-sensitive) is working for me in ROS Melodic. `<turngravityoff>` all-lowercase doesn't work.